# How to dealing with this message 'You've added another git repository inside your current repository.'

Tags: git, github, build, git-revert

What happen was I merged the code on git yesterday, I realize code was built.
So I revert to previous git log and fix it( no build , update some code)

And now when I tried to `git add.`

I got this message

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: Carebnb
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> Carebnb
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached Carebnb
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information
```

I don't know why the git recoginze I tried to submodule it..

What I want is just push on the github ..!

+
What happen was My code was link with Carebnb repository, But merge was not working so I made new hotel_app repository and link! After then  I revert of Carebnb repository and now When I git add It has these message

Comment: The folder `Carebnb` is a git repository. Check how it has been created. `git add .` adds all the files and directories under the current path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This code link with git Carebnb repository.   So it it normal!  hmm... I think current path also Carebnb

Comment: Hmm..  What happen was It was link with Carebnb repository, But merge was not working so I made new hotel_app repository and link! After then  I revert of Carebnb repository and now When I git add It has these message

Comment: Do you want `Carebnb` to be part of your repository? If yes, you could either add it as a submodule or just copy its code of a specific revision to your repository. It depends on how you plan to maintain it in the future. If no, you could just remove it by `git rm --cached Carebnb`.